# When do partial derivatives fail to commute?

Tags: derivatives, continuity, partial-derivative

What are the conditions that a function $f(x,y)$ should satisfy for the partial derivatives $f_{xy}$ and $f_{yx}$ to be equal?

Comment: You need the function to be twice continuously differentiable (aka of class $C^2$).  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_of_second_derivatives#Schwarz.27s_theorem

Comment: @Crostul since the OP commented on my post I came back to this question and just saw your comment. Note that the twice differentiability is **sufficient** but not **necessary**, so you don't "need" this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[See Here](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/HighOrderPartialDerivs.aspx)

> **Clairaut’s Theorem**
>
> Suppose that $f$ is defined on a disk $D$ that contains
>   the point $(a,b)$.  If the functions  $f_{xy}$ and $f_{yx}$ are continuous on this disk then
>   $$f_{xy}(a,b) =f_{yx}(a,b)$$

We can actually restrict ourselves a bit less and let $D$ be any open subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$, which generalizes nicely to

> **[Extended Clairaut’s Theorem](https://calculus.subwiki.org/wiki/Clairaut%27s_theorem_on_equality_of_mixed_partials)**
>
> Suppose $f$ is a function of  variables defined on an open subset $D$ or $\mathbb{R}^n$. Suppose ***all*** mixed partials with each possible number of and combination of differentiations in each input variable exist and are continuous on $D$. Then, all the mixed partials are continuous.

Comment: Can you give a simple example of a function $f(x,y)$ where $f_{xy}\neq f_{yx}$? @Brevan Ellefsen

Comment: @SRS see here https://calculus.subwiki.org/wiki/Failure_of_Clairaut's_theorem_where_both_mixed_partials_are_defined_but_not_equal